# How do I set default values for jqGrid single-search fields

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to set the default column selection on a jqGrid single-search dialog.

The options available are described on [the jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching)

To set the default search "type" option, I re-ordered the "*sopt*" array with the value I need ("contains", "cn") first in the array and set this on the `navGrid` search options.  Despite browsing the source code I have not been able to work out which property might affect the initial field selection.  It always defaults to the first column in my `colModel`.

My code is:

```
$('#tableid').jqGrid({
    colNames: ['ID', 'Membership#', 'Join Date', 'Email', 'Name', 'Address', 'Postcode'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'ID',       index:'ID',       hidden:true },
        {name:'MEMID',    index:'MEMD',     width:90 },
        {name:'JOINDATE', index:'JOINDATE', width:70 },
        {name:'EMAIL',    index:'EMAIL',    width:150, align:"right" },
        {name:'NAME',     index:'NAME',     width:120, align:"right" },
        {name:'ADDRESS',  index:'ADDRESS',  width:250, align:"right" },
        {name:'POSTCODE', index:'POSTCODE', width:80,  align:"right" }
      ],
      // etc. ...
});

$("#tableid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { /* parameters */
      edit:false, add:false, del:false, searchtext:'Find&nbsp;', refreshtext:'Refresh&nbsp;' 
    },
    { /* edit options */ },
    { /* add options */ },
    { /* delete options */ },
    { /* search options */
      multipleSearch:false,
      multipleGroup:false,
      showQuery:false,
      top: 190,
      left: 200,
      caption: "Search for members...",
      closeAfterSearch: false,
      sopt: ['cn','nc','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en'],
    },
    { /* view options */ }
);
```

When the user clicks on "Find"  I would like the initial default search dialog to be presented with "Name", "contains" selected.

Comment: see **UPDATED** part of my answer

Comment: Oleg, I should have said thanks last year for your answer, your support for jqgrid on stackoverflow has been invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good question! jqGrid contains the option `columns` which can be used to implement your requirements, but the usage of the option is not simple. So I made the demo for you.

[The option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) `columns` of searching dialog is not documented probably because it's not really user friendly. The option `columns` can contains array of items of `colModel`. Exactly the items in the same order will be used in construction of the drop-down select with column names. Per default jqGrid fill `columns` with all items of `colModel` which don't have `search: false` property. For hidden columns (having `hidden: true`) it will be tested additionally `searchoptions.searchhidden` property (see [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L103-L129) of the source code). So the option `columns` will be filled internally per default. On the other side one can overwrite the option `columns` to have custom order of searching fields.

The code which you included in the text of your question produced the following searching dialog

[image]

After filling option `columns` you can change it to for example the following

[image]

The corresponding demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfSearchingOptionsEdRandall.htm). The most important parts of the code are below

```js
var $grid = $('#tableid'),
    getColumnByName = function (colName) {
        var colModel = $.extend([], this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")),
            colNames = $.extend([], this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colNames")),
            l = colModel.length, i, cm;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            cm = colModel[i];
            if (cm.name === colName) {
                cm.label = cm.label || colNames[i];
                return cm;
            }
        }
    };
$grid.jqGrid({
    colNames: ['ID', 'Membership#', 'Join Date', 'Email', 'Name', 'Address', 'Postcode'],
    colModel: [
      {name: 'ID',       hidden: true },
      {name: 'MEMID',    width: 90 },
      {name: 'JOINDATE', width: 70 },
      {name: 'EMAIL',    width: 150, align: "right" },
      {name: 'NAME',     width: 120, align: "right" },
      {name: 'ADDRESS',  width: 250, align: "right" },
      {name: 'POSTCODE', width: 80,  align: "right" }
    ],
    ...
});
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { /* parameters */
      edit:false, add:false, del:false, searchtext:'Find&nbsp;', refreshtext:'Refresh&nbsp;' 
    },
    { /* edit options */ },
    { /* add options */ },
    { /* delete options */ },
    { /* search options */
        ...
        columns: [
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'NAME'),
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'EMAIL'),
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'JOINDATE'),
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'MEMID'),
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'ADDRESS'),
            getColumnByName.call($grid, 'POSTCODE')
        ]
    },
    { /* view options */ }
);
```

**UPDATED**: There are small bug in Single Value Searching (`multipleSearch: true` not set) and setting of `columns` option. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467819/315935) I describe how the bug can be fixed. Alternatively you can use `multipleSearch: true` option and specify `filters` with default searching rule in `postData` (see the same answer).