# How to set the default column for the search box in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I have specified which columns are searchable through the `colModel`, but I can't find a way to specify the default column when the search box is opened.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are option `columns` which is not documented in [the list of searching options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options). I wrote recently [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16396486/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfSearchingOptionsEdRandall.htm) which demonstrate how you can implement your requirement.

**UPDATED**: If you use `multipleSearch: true` option then you can just follow the referenced answer and specify `columns` option like I described. The corresponding demo you find [**here**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfColumnInAdvancedSearching.htm). If you don't like that `multipleSearch: true` option don't display any searching rule per default you can just add default rule in `filters` property of `postData`. For example [**the next demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfColumnInAdvancedSearching0.htm) is identical to the previous one but it uses additionally

```js
postData: {
    filters: {groupOp: "AND", rules: [{field: "amount", op: "eq", data: ""}]}
}
```

option.

If you don't want to use `multipleSearch: true` option then one have to fix small bug in jqGrid to be able to use `columns` option. One have to modify [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L127-L129) (see the line 7009 in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) from

```js
} else {
    columns = p.columns;
}
```

to

```js
} else {
    columns = p.columns;
    cmi = 0;
    colnm = columns[0].index || columns[0].name;
}
```

I will post the bug report later to trirand and I hope that the bug will be fixed in the next version of jqGrid.

[**The demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfColumnInSingleValueSearching.htm) demonstrate working of the suggested fix.

Comment: the solution works to change the order and therefore default to the value I want, but as soon as I hit search, the `searchField` parameters is null. If I change the column then `searchField` is sent to the server.

Comment: @JonasStawski: You mean probably *initial* search rule. I will fix the problem tomorrow (It's late now in Germany :-)).

Comment: @JonasStawski: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.