# After setting default search column in jqGrid, how to include searchField as url parameter?

Tags: jqgrid

I've implemented the answer given [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387287/how-do-i-set-default-values-for-jqgrid-single-search-fields) and it works but the resulting URL that is generated when the user clicks the search/find button does not include the **searchField** parameter and thus my server code does not return data.  If I remove the columns:[ ] section of search options, my search columns are no longer sorted, but the **searchField** returns to the URL.  Is there something else I can do to return this parameter to the query string?

Below is my pager code.

```
$("#AllContactsTable").jqGrid('navGrid', "#AllContactsPager", {
                            search: true,
                            refresh: false,
                            reload: false,
                            add: false,
                            del: false,
                            edit: false
                        }, {}, {}, {}
                        , {
                            overlay: 0,
                            width: 650,
                            top: 0,
                            left: 100

                            //,columns: [
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'LastName'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'FirstName'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'MiddleName'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'HomePhoneNumber'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'CellPhoneNumber'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'WorkPhoneNumber'),
                            //        getColumnByName.call($grid, 'ContactID')
                            //]
                        });
```

Comment: Updating to latest jqGrid solved the problem.  Thanks Oleg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem which you described, but can't. All works correctly. In **UPDATED** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16396486/315935) I referenced [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467819/315935) where I describe the bug in version 4.4.5 (and more old versions too). The fix which I suggested are fixed in the (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/cee055801145efa656ea4f4bd9f4736032f741a2)). The version 4.5 and the current version 4.5.2 of jqGrid included the fix.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfColumnInSingleValueSearching0.htm) demonstrate that all works correctly. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OrderOfColumnInSingleValueSearching0_.htm) set `datatype: "json"` and `url: "someDummyUrl"`. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to trace HTTP traffic. You will see the URL will be correctly appended with `searchField`, `searchString` and `searchOper`:

```
searchField=amount&searchString=200&searchOper=eq&filters=
```