# jqgrid dynamically change "dropdown column select" in search modal

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need to be able to dynamically modify the content of the dropdown "select.selectLabel" in the which are created inside the "div.searchFilter" > "td.columns". Which I need is to add or remove certain search columns when the user selects some external options.

I know these selects are based on the colModel, and they are all recreated every time the user add a new search rule. So it's difficult to alter them via dataInit() function, because my changes are lost everytime new rule is added. Even I find the element like...

`dataInit: function(elem) {
    $(elem).closest("td.data").siblings(".columns").find("select.selectLabel");
}`

then removing specific `<option>` and adding new ones, it seems to take no effect.
I wonder if there is some way to "tell" the searchpanel the new ColModel, but
I don't want to alter the grid, just ONLY the columns for search modal.

Thanks
(version freejqgrid 4.13)

**EDIT 1:** To be clear (Oleg's comment)... 
I am using datatype=ajax (server data).

I have a regular colModel, but I want to modify the search panel dropdowns (combo-boxes) to add/remove some fields, NOT altering the grid colmodel.
I mean, add/remove some `<option>` (both value and label), and add some new ones with new "pseudo-fields" which are not in the former colModel.

I tried the searchoptions.dataInit() function to get every new rule (so I can reach the corresponding `<select class="selectLabel">`), but found this function not easy to use for my needs.

Now I'm trying the searchoptions.afterRedraw() but I'm not sure if this will help me.

**EDIT 2:**
Supose I have this

```
colModel: [
    {name:"country", label:"Country", search:true},
    {name:"city", label:"City", search:true},
    {name:"zip", label:"Zip Code", search:true}
]
```

When user opens the search modal, he will add a new rule and select the field from the dropbox which has...

```
<select class="selectLabel">
    <option value="country">Country</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="zip">Zip Code</option>
</select>
```

Then, the user clicks an external button, which fires an event that will MODIFY any column dropbox (present or future), which should be...

```
<select class="selectLabel">
    <option value="country">Country</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="zip">Zip Code</option>
    <option value="phone1">Phone 1</option> //dynamically added
    <option value="phone2">Phone 2</option> //dynamically added
    <option value="phone3">Phone 3</option> //dynamically added
    //(and so on...)
</select>
```

These new pseudo-fields (phone1, phone2 ...) are not present in the colModel, since they are created onthefly by some external code.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem correctly. Which `datatype` you use in jqGrid? Do you have *local* data or not? Could you provide small demo (in jsfiddle, for example) with 2-3 columns and some test data, which demonstrates the problem. Do you want only change dynamically **the label** displayed in the Searching Dialog or you want to search for property which exist in data, but for which there are no column in `colModel`? The most things are possible, but I want be sure that I understand correctly what you need.

Comment: now you can refresh my question, EDIT 1 & 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted the demo, which I could modify. Because of that I describe only what you can do. Searching Dialog of jqGrid contains `columns` parameter. The Searching Dialog contains the information based on the option if it exist. It the option isn't exist then the copy of `colModel` will be used. Thus you are able to fill `columns` dynamically with any information which you want and Searching dialog will contain it. Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16396486/315935) or in [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog.htm) for code examples, which uses `columns` parameter.

Comment: i weisted the las half hour triying to EDIT my question adding formatted code, but Stackoverflow seems to dislike my code and rejects my edition.

Comment: Oleg, your answer is correct, I will try with "columns" parameter in Searching options. I didn't knew it, 
I need to modify that "columns" option everytime I need, not on grid init. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: I still can't get how to modifiy the columns (or colModel) and update all the filters dropdowns, after $grid was already created

Comment: @Aberel: You should provide **the demo** (in jsfiddle for example), which demonstrates what you do currently. After I'll see your code and can reproduce your problem I can try to help you.

Comment: @Aberel: Look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7k4dv191/30/ for example. You see two search buttons. Both displays different labels. The most easy to fill the `columns` parameter dynamically will be if you calls `searchGrid` *directly* like in the code from `onClickButton` callback of the demo. Alternatively you can place `columns` inside of `searching` parameter of jqGrid. You can use `var s = $("#grid1").jqGrid("getGridParam", "searching");` to get the searching parameter and to assign new `columns` just using `s.columns = anotherArray`. Thus I'm not sure *where* you have problems.

Comment: Oleg, i will look at your demo, then I tell you if solves my question, thanks!

Comment: Oleg, I created a demo from yours, please read the comments in the javascript block.  
https://jsfiddle.net/aberel/2gretsnh/31/